# Time Capsule first backup is slow (like a week to complete)

Tags: wifi, catalina, time-capsule

I haven't seen "my" answer to this problem so I am posting both Q & A here.

I am doing initial WiFi backup of 265GB on a 16" MacBook Pro, running system 10.15.1, to a 2TB Time Capsule. I have done full backups many times before: they have been slow, but not like this. Today's backup includes *long* stretches of no network activity, punctuated by brief – but small — bursts.

[image]

The progress bar declines to offer a prediction, but my estimate is about a week.

I have rebooted, erased the Time Capsule (via AirPort Utility, not Disk Utility) twice and re-started. Apps like Music and Photos were closed anyway. Tried the throttle hack (https://www.imore.com/how-speed-your-time-machine-backups). Pored through dozens of outdated suggestions online.

What finally got it rolling? Answer to follow.

Answer (score 1):

After about six hours of waiting for Godot, I tried this experiment: put the Mac to sleep (power *not* connected) and see if (still sloooow) backup proceeds while sleeping. It did not. (I let it sleep for a half hour, so the presence or absence of progress would be more apparent.) *But*... on re-awakening, the backup was more than 10x faster.

[image: screenshot of network activity]

Also, I found that when power *is* connected, backup *does* continue while sleeping. (PowerNap feature, checkbox in System Preferences > Energy Saver panel.) So while both laptop and I were asleep, 90% of the backup completed.

Solution? I don't know how general it is, and this is post-hoc reasoning, but my suggestion is: try putting your Mac to sleep for a while, with power *disconnected*. On awakening, it might just be 10x faster.

Comment: When you mac is not idle, TM tends to be slow. See https://gist.github.com/mayankk2308/00cc5be0bb8b150e3d7a149a3387c1d4.

Comment: Another technique is to exclude many things for the first backup, and add them back later.

Comment: Yes I agree with both points. And yet... the same trick just worked again for me. After migrating my Photos and Music libraries (I still use hard-copies!) the subsequent backup was large and slow -- pauses of several minutes between small bursts. Packets out/sec less than 1000. Go to sleep and wake up: packets out/sec >40,000.